# How to create an obstacle that sends the player in the air?

Tags: unreal-4, unreal

I'm making a game in UE4.25 and I have several obstacles in there. I want them to send the player in the air if the player walks or stumbles into them. (Kind of like a Fall Guys effect, like if you get hit by a nearby falling ball, you fall into the void or something.)

Is there a possible way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a force to the character when they trigger the obstacle. Use [AddForce](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/BlueprintAPI/Pawn/Components/CharacterMovement/AddForce/index.html) if you are using blueprints or [UPrimitiveComponent::AddForce](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/Components/UPrimitiveComponent/AddForce/index.html) if you are in C++.

Comment: For a sudden launching effect, rather than a gradual levitation, you may prefer AddImpulse - this represents a single sharp kick, rather than an acceleration over the duration that the object remains in the force field. You can always scale up a one-time force to act like an impulse for a given time step, but if your time step changes, the motion you get from that force also changes, while impulses stay consistent because they don't integrate over time.